# TypeError: res.sendStatus is not a function - Why do I keep getting this error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I have been working in Node.js/Express in making a REST Api for the past several months. I'm running into this issue with my async function in my controller.js file. My callback function receives my `request` from the client but when I want to send a `response` I keep getting this `TypeError: res.sendStatus is not a function` Error.

Here's my code:

`index.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const { parseData } = require("../controllers/parse.controller");
const { checkFirebaseLogin } = require("../controllers/checkFirebaseLogin.controller");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var router = express.Router();

router.use(bodyParser.json());  
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

router.post('/api/idToken', checkFirebaseLogin);
router.post('/', parseData);

module.exports = router
```

Here is my Controller.js file

`checkFirebaseLogin.controller.js`

```
const { checkUserLogin } = require("../services/checkUserLogin.service");

const checkFirebaseLogin = async (req, res) => {
    console.log("Checking on user token ...");
    const userToken = req.headers;

    try {
        var userUID = await checkUserLogin(userToken);
        console.log("Here's the repsonse:");
        console.log(userUID)
        res.sendStatus(201)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("I'm here right before the error message on checking the user token")
        //console.log(error.message);
        console.log(error)
    }

};

module.exports = {
    checkFirebaseLogin
};
```

I am able to get the `req.headers` but when I try to send a response (via `res.sendStatus(200)`) back to the client I always get an error. Where I am going wrong?

**Updated: Jan 12**
Also, is here is my app.js so that you can see how I'm dealing with my routes. The client (based on my code would go from the `app.js -> routes/index.js -> controllers/checkFirebaseLogin.controller.js`)

`app.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require("http");
var app = express();
const routes = require('./routers');

//app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('App is working'));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/api/idToken', routes);

http.createServer(routes).listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("server up");
});

module.exports = {
    app
};
```

Comment: Are you sure it's throwing in that code? Show the full stack trace. Because the only way that error can be thrown is if `res` is not an Express Response object.

Comment: Usually, this error happens when you have accidentally defined some other local variable (often a callback argument) to be `res` and it overrides the `res` that was passed into the request handler.  Then, when you're trying to call `res.sendStatus()`, it's the wrong `res` object.  You don't show that here, but it doesn't look like this code would cause that error so I suspect some other code you haven't shown us is causing this.

Comment: Note: separate issue, but you also need to send some status/response in your `catch` handler.

Comment: @jfriend00 what other code do you need to see? My app.js?

Comment: I'd suggest you add a `console.log("Before", typeof res.sendStatus, res);` right before the `res.sendStatus(201);` and a `console.log("After");` right after the `res.sendStatus(201)`.  Three goals here.  First, see if `res.sendStatus` is a function there, see if `res` is the object you expect it to be and with the second one to see if the error actually occurs before you get to the second console message to see if this is actually where the error is occuring.

Comment: @jfriend00 I get something like the following below
`Before undefined <ref *2> ServerResponse {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] { finish: [Function: bound resOnFinish] },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  outputData: [],
  outputSize: 0,
  writable: true,
`
And I never get to the the `console.log("After")`.

Comment: @jeff-ridgeway - What version of Express are you running?  `sendStatus()` was not always available so wouldn't be present in some versions.  You could try `res.status(201).end()` as an alternative or update your version of Express to the latest 4.x version.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm running 4.17.1 (which is the most stable version looking on the website)

Comment: Why do you have both `app.use('/', routes);` and `app.use('/api/idToken', routes);`?  You're putting the exact same functionality at two different URLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does appear that you aren't setting up your http server and Express `app` object correctly.  You're trying to pass a `router` to a plain http server - that's not going to work.  You need to pass a router to an `app.use()`.

Change from this:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require("http");
var app = express();
const routes = require('./routers');

//app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('App is working'));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/api/idToken', routes);

http.createServer(routes).listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("server up");
});

module.exports = {
    app
};
```

to this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const routes = require('./routers');

//app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('App is working'));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/api/idToken', routes);

app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("server up");
});

module.exports = {
    app
};
```

The key here is that the `app` object, NOT the `router` object needs to be passed to the http server.  In this modified code, we use `app.listen()` to create the server which does that for us automatically.  In your original code, you could have done:

```
http.createServer(app).listen(...)
```

Note passing `app`, instead of `router`.  But, I prefer to just use `app.listen()` which is designed as a coding shortcut for this (it creates the http server object for you).

Also, this looks suspicious:

```
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/api/idToken', routes);
```

Because you're making the exact same functionality be present at two different URL locations (unless that's what you oddly intended).  You can technically do this, but it's very unusual so I'm wondering if that's really what you intended.

Comment: I am running the latest version of Express (4.17.1) and I tried `res.status(201).send('Created');`. However that didn't work. I've added my app.js to the original question as you wanted to see how I've hooked my router into my express app
`

Comment: @jeff-ridgeway - OK, finally can see a major issue.  I rewrote my answer.

Comment: that worked! I will also change the routes that look suspicious later. Thanks!

Comment: @jeff-ridgeway - Awesome.  Just needed to see the other part of your code.

Answer (score -1):

You did not initialize express properly.

```
var app = express();
...
var router = express.Router();
app.use(bodyParser.json());  
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

router.post('/api/idToken', checkFirebaseLogin);
router.post('/', parseData);
...
app.use(router);
```